# Show YouTube video main page Drupal

Tags: drupal, youtube

I would like to show a youtube video when someone arrives on my drupal website. So basically, I want to launch a video in the main page as an overlay to the site. 
How could I do? If it is possible without installing any modules?

I'd really appreciate any help, Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: Do you need this popup in all pages or only in the first visit?

Comment: I only need in the first visit

Answer (score 2):

You could use a JavaScript modal to act as the container to play the YouTube video.
Then use PHP sessions to determine if the JS modal has to be launched or skipped.

Comment: It could be a solution, although I was looking some thing easier. I mean, I don't need the session because the video would be launch every time someone get the websites. I did a simple project with php in which I am able to launch a pretty popup video when you get the website. For this, I have added in the index.php 3 js file + 1 css, then I have put in the "body" tag a load... and finally just a little script inside. See http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/ to have a close Idea of what I am looking to do. So my question is if it would be possible modify the index.php directly.. Thanks

Comment: Without knowing much about the structure of your site, you could modify the index.php directly. Adding JS or PHP to it. One simple, yet hackish way to get around it is to put the videobox code into your index.php and have it as a clickable, but hidden link.  Then use JS to 'click' the target ID.

Personally, I am not a fan of doing it like that.  I would use [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) to add the videobox and JS code to separate variables to be echo'd into the index file.

Comment: Well, I have figure it out and it was something similar like you said before. I've got it and it works fine. For now, I am happy with that, although I imagine there are other ways to do that. I had a look to your link. However, I have an architecture in which all the Drupals website share a multi-site environment. Even more I don't have a particular staging or testing website and with my knowledge about Drupal if I follow this approach it would be so much complicated (in terms of time). Anyway, thank you so much. I will get more fun getting that this appears only once instead of every time.